# In Android java, how do I catch long press on Bluetooth device call button?

Tags: android, button, bluetooth

How do I catch (intercept) a long Bluetooth device call button press (android)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for is `android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND`, and it's an Activity intent, not a Receiver intent.  You need the following in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name="LongPressActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The problem arises once your activity starts.  Most of the APIs used in the Voice Command application are hidden, so you have to jump through flaming hoops to access them.  Either use reflection, or see [this series of articles](https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/).

Comment: Since Jelly Bean wouldn't Google Now intercept that intent instead of your own activity?

Answer (score 2):

You mean the `Intent.ACTION_CALL_BUTTON` action but than for a long press? That doesn't exist, Android offers only a limited amount of standard actions and long press on physical buttons is not included.

Although if it is possible when your own activity is open, by overriding the `onKeyLongPress` method in your activity class.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CALL) {
        // do your stuff here
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Typically, when you press the Bluetooth headset and its call button for about 2 seconds, it gives a long beep. I've already seen some Android programs using this action instead of a single press on device's button, so I thought this is somewhere defined with its own action. Double press I could use as well, bit that usually auto dials last call.

Comment: Actually, looking at this KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CALL, are you sure it'll work with press of the call button on a Bluetooth headset device? I am not getting it to work, for some reason...

Comment: Maybe the Bluetooth headset triggers the `Intent.ACTION_CALL` or the `Intent.ACTION_DIAL`, maybe you can monitor double pressing by checking in your broadcast receiver if the button has been pressed again.

Comment: Hm, nothing of that sort. I have just found this article though.I will test and report: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287116/android-registering-a-headset-button-click-with-broadcastreceiver

Comment: It didn't help. I can't figure this out, spending literally days searching entire internet. Is there any authority on these types of things here on this board?