# Catch press bluetooth button in android?

Tags: android, button, bluetooth

Is is possible to receive a button press , long press , or continuous presses via bluetooth?
Can this be handled with KeyEvent?

Comment: Make it clear, what exactly do you want to achive?

Comment: Well, i want to trigger an activity by long pressing the call button on a bluetooth headset!

Comment: See my answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792636/in-android-java-how-do-i-catch-long-press-on-bluetooth-device-call-button/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the brand/model of the bluetooth headset. Check specific vendor headset API to see if long press event is supported (most only support single-press only).

Comment: Is it an issue of the headset then , and not the programmer to handle these events?

Comment: @dothedos yes it is.