# How to handle AT commands from a Bluetooth headset in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, at-command, headset

I would like to handle an AT command (for double tap event) from a standard Bluetooth mono headset. By default, the double tap sends AT+BLDN command (Redial event) to the phone. According to Android documentation, registering a Broadcast Receiver for

> android.bluetooth.headset.action.VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT

will handle all such vendor related AT commands. But, it is not being invoked when the AT command is sent by the headset. Though, the redial event happens on the phone.

Comment: Are u on Jellybean version

Comment: No, I am on 4.0.3. I have the problem in jelly bean also.

Comment: Please have a look @ https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/, per my understanding AT commands are handled in hfp/HeadsetStateMachine.java ..i will also have a look though not sure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**AT+BLDN** is a standard(GSM) command for redialing. So it is handled by the system itself.Moreover as per my understanding the device should support those specific commands which are for ex:plantronics specific command then only user will be able to get notification about that command.