# Using earphone key press event

Tags: android, android-hardware

I want to use earphone key event to make some event handling on that.
I haven't tried it at all because i don't have any base for this type of event handling.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` and `ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY` (volume loud control). 
But be aware that you shouldnt have another headset app running in the background as it can take a higher priority over yours. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287116/android-registering-a-headset-button-click-with-broadcastreceiver) for more details on the know how's

Comment: I want to use button of my mobile earphone which is used to receive/make a call(by pressing button once) and to start/pause music(by pressing button twice immediately). I want to listen long key press event of earphone.