# Android - How to detect middle button click of headphone?

Tags: android, android-studio, development-environment

I'm developing an application that control the middle button of headphone (maybe it calls play/pause button). But I detect the plug but I don't know to control the button click. How can I do? Thanks.

P.S. Sorry for my English :)

Comment: which key is smart key ??

Comment: pressy key instead of headphone? Yo man, You have to be more clear, nobody understands Your question....

Comment: For smart key I mean the middle button of the headphone. Sorry for the issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287116/android-registering-a-headset-button-click-with-broadcastreceiver

Comment: Benjamin I just tried this but it doesn't work.

Comment: Benjamin thank you; now this work. But if I use two broadcast receiver, it works only one broadcast receiver. Why?