# BroadcostReceiver MEDIA_BUTTON key_down key_up

Tags: java, android, button, headset

How to process events of `key_down` and `key_up` separately (different methods) for the button on a headset of `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON`?

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far. We can't guess what you are trying to do from a one-line description.

Comment: I used a standard script (the description on this website) for processing of pressing of the ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON button
But by long pressing Google search is caused, and I should process key_down and key_up separately

Comment: [code like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287116/android-registering-a-headset-button-click-with-broadcastreceiver)

Comment: Really, I haven't correctly raised a question))
In that example there is a division, on events necessary for me..., but how to disconnect Google search by long pressing the button?

Comment: For this purpose it is necessary to shut down the Google app in settings. And search won't appear

Comment: But shutdown search Google, hasn't solved a problem...
By short-term pressing everything works, but if to clamp the button for some time, then events aren't processed

Comment: if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        action(1);
        }

if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        action(2);
        }