# Bluetooth Headphone Button Triggering in Android studio, SDK level Min API 15 and Max API 28

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-developer-api

I need to detect the bluetooth HeadPhone device button click in my application. I followed many stackoverflow links, but doesn't seem to work for me.

Actual Working, When Headphone Button Clicked, Text apper in application "Button Pressed" or any other else

In this link I have tried, API 28 but its not Working
[Registering a headset button click with BroadcastReceiver in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287116/registering-a-headset-button-click-with-broadcastreceiver-in-android)

No Error and No Output

public class RemoteControlReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
public RemoteControlReceiver(){
    super();
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String intentAction = intent.getAction();
    Log.i ("TAG", intentAction.toString() + " happended");
    if (!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
        Log.i ("TAG", "no media button information");
        return;
    }
    KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
    if (event == null) {
        Log.i ("TAG", "no keypress");
        return;
    }

}
```

MainActivity

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    RemoteControlReceiver r = new RemoteControlReceiver();
    registerReceiver(r, filter);
```

Comment: what you have tried please mention

Comment: This Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287116/registering-a-headset-button-click-with-broadcastreceiver-in-android